# Pass variable value to Object Method

Tags: delphi

I'm working with TWebBrowser, and some of it's methods to get a JavaScript variable value on the current document, is doing:

```
value:= WebBrowser1.Document; 
Result:= value.Script.myVar;
```

The example above, the javascript should have a global 'myVar' variable set. To avoid rewriting this code many times, I want to do a function where I'll send the variable name to be grabbed:

```
function TForm1.GetJSVariableValue(VarName: string): String;
var
  value: OleVariant;
begin
  value:= WebBrowser1.Document;
  Result:= value.Script.VarName;
end;
```

Of course this is not working, because Delphi interprets it as I'm trying to access a method 'VarName', which doesn't exists. Is there any way to get around this problem and actually pass the VarName value as a method name?

Comment: Do you want to save a variable within the HTML document, and retrieve its value in Delphi?

Comment: Yes... I solved the problem creating the variable I want with always the same name.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that.  Are you using document.getElementById ?

Comment: No... The variable is available to me via the WebBrowser1.Document.Script.VariableName method...

Comment: you should post a working example as an answer